# What does Wireshark do to the network configuration when it starts monitoring

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireshark

I frequently have to connect to industrial controllers, more often than not these are on networks with no DHCP where all devices are assigned a static IP.

I have found recently I have been having issues connecting to or even pinging these controllers after assigning myself to the same subnet with an unused static IP.

As part of troubleshooting I though I would open Wireshark and see if I could spot anything funny going on, however as soon as I select the interface in Wireshark to open and start recorded the connection comes good immediately and I am able to ping or connect normally to the controllers.

The problem remains fixed even after closing Wireshark, at some point the issue comes back but usually not the same day.

I suspect this potentially an issue caused by some corporate management/security/monitoring software forced onto the PC, but IT support has been unable to resolve the issue.

What exactly does Wireshark do when it taps into an interface for logging, so that I can get some clues as to what might be configured wrong and Wireshark is inadvertently fixing.

My first thought was something in the routing table but it appears unchanged before and during running wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it's putting your interface in promiscuous mode, which means it won't ignore packets that were sent to a different device's hardware MAC address. It also means your interface will receive all multicasts, even ones the OS had not asked the interface to listen to.

Comment: Would you be able to explain what effect that might have on the process of pinging a device.

Comment: I'm guessing something's going wrong with ARP tables in some way, but I'd want to look at the packet trace. Anyway, to test my theory that it's about promisc mode, you can tell Wireshark *not* to put the interface in promisc mode, and see if that keeps the act of capturing from fixing the problem.

Comment: Running it with promiscuous mode unchecked still fixed the issue, as before I also note that it continues working after wireshark is closed. I don't really understand arp tables and their role, but if I run arp -a before opening wireshark It shows the interface for my wifi adapter (how I was previously connected to the corporate network, even though I am disconnected) after running wireshark arp -a returns the interface of the wired adapter in my laptop (which I am using to connect to the controller), would screencaps of this help?

Comment: I have re-run before and after spitting arp -a -v into a text file, doing a diff on them before and after the only difference is "192.168.0.55          00-00-00-00-00-00     invalid " changes to "192.168.0.55          00-50-a0-99-4e-42     dynamic"

Comment: @Hugoagogo If you make that ARP mapping static/permanent (with something like `sudo arp -s 192.168.0.55 00:50:a0:99:4e:42`), does that solve the problem without starting Wireshark? That might be an interesting data point to gather. What do you mean about the `arp` command showing interfaces? What OS are we talking about here? You might need to show me the output of `arp`. Also, do you have the ability to see the ARP tables in the Delta controllers?

Comment: OS is win10pro, I will try that test next time the issue occurs, in addition I should note that the same issue occurs with other bits of gear for example when setting up access points for the first time (variety that ships with dhcp off and a fixed up)

Comment: Are you using the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet on more than one network that you're switching between? Like, do you use it on the corporate network as well as on the industrial controller network? I'm beginning to wonder if you've got stale ARP entries for the old network. It might be interesting to see if running `sudo arp -ad` (or whatever the Win10 equivalent would be) would clear this up.

Comment: I believe the corporate network contains does contain the 192.168.0.0/24 range but not for anything that I directly access. I will give that a go, so I understand, that command clears all entries in the arp table, and the arp table is responsible for keeping track of what IP address have what MAC addresses.

Comment: @Hugoagogo That's right.